# cannot import name 'greedy_modularity_communities'

Tags: python-3.6, networkx

I used networkx to generate my directed graph. I want to use [`greedy_modularity_communities(G, weight=None)`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.community.modularity_max.greedy_modularity_communities.html#networkx.algorithms.community.modularity_max.greedy_modularity_communities) to find communities in my graph.
As it is mentioned in [Networkx documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/algorithms/community.html) I am importing the following modules.

```
from networkx.algorithms import community

from networkx.algorithms.community import greedy_modularity_communities
```

but I get an error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'greedy_modularity_communities'

Comment: Can you tell us what version of networkx you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from the URL you linked, the docs you're looking at are from "latest", and on the top left of the page you can see the version that those docs are from is "2.2rc1.dev_20180504030509", which is a release candidate for version 2.2 which hasn't been released yet.

If you want, you could install the development version as explained in the [networkx docs](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/install.html#install-the-development-version), after which it should work:

```
>>> import networkx
>>> networkx.__version__
'2.2rc1.dev_20180521153746'
>>> from networkx.algorithms.community import greedy_modularity_communities
>>> print(greedy_modularity_communities.__doc__)
Find communities in graph using Clauset-Newman-Moore greedy modularity
    maximization. This method currently supports the Graph class and does not
    consider edge weights.

    Greedy modularity maximization begins with each node in its own community
    and joins the pair of communities that most increases modularity until no
    such pair exists.
    [...]
```

but as usual, you should be aware of the dangers of using prerelease versions of software packages: there are often bugs which haven't yet been fixed and testing which isn't complete.  Coder beware.

Answer (score 1):

The newest version of networkx seems to have moved greedy_modularity_communities to the modularity_max module, as seen [here](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/master/networkx/algorithms/community/modularity_max.py).

This is not yet included in the version of the package you'll install via PIP, so if you require this function you may want to try the latest dev version.

Comment: That's where it's _implemented_, but it's imported by `community/__init__.py`, which makes `community` the standard place to pull it from (see [here](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/master/networkx/algorithms/community/__init__.py)) .

Comment: Right, thanks, I didn't mean to imply that he was importing from the wrong spot, just that the module where this function was implemented likely isn't a part of the version he's using, which would explain the import error.